# Input String was not in a correct format in F#

Tags: f#, formatexception

Could anyone tell me and explain to me what's wrong with this code?

```
open System
let hexarea t:float =
    (3.0*Math.Sqrt(3.0)/2.0) * Math.Pow(t, 2.0)
let value = float (Console.ReadLine())
let calc = hexarea value
printfn "%f" calc
```

I can give a hint - it works when it's like:

```
open System
let hexarea t : float =
    (3.0 * Math.Sqrt(3.0) / 2.0) * Math.Pow(t,2.0)
[<EntryPoint>]  
    let main argv =
    let value = float (Console.ReadLine())
    let calc  = hexarea value
    printf "%f" calc
    0
```

By the way, if I remove 0 from the last line, it's complaining..

Please clarify to me what's happening.

Thanks.

Comment: [Your code works just fine](https://ideone.com/yjFcW1). As to needing the 0, when you use `EntryPoint` the function it's applied to must return an `int`.

Comment: The code is working fine, No need for <EntryPoint>.  When a program has no EntryPoint attribute that explicitly indicates the entry point, the top level bindings in the last file is used as the entry point.

Comment: But if we're not about to return something? what value should I return? 0 seems to have a conventional meaning of "OK Executed" .. but how general it is? it's sort of just convention or mandatory rule to return 0 ?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri : The .NET convention is to do as C does, which is to return 0 for success or 1 for error. Adhering to this convention is completely optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting "Input String was not in a correct format" exception as the title of your question suggests, this is likely because the number you are entering in the `Console.ReadLine` is not in the correct format.

This is a continuous pain-point if you're from a country that uses decimal comma rather than decimal dot. In Czech, we write `3,14` and so if you set the current culture to `cs-CZ` you get:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture <- 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("cs-CZ")

float "1.0" // Works because this uses invariant culture
System.Double.Parse("1.0") // Fails because this uses cs-CZ culture now

float "1,0" // Fails because the invariant culture requires .
System.Double.Parse("1,0") // Works according to cs-CZ culture
```